# 12.04.3--- Dconf Editor won't show com>canonical>unity option

Tags: unity, dconf

Hi there (sorry about bad english), i want to tweak something in unity, but i can't see "unity" option in "Dconf editor > com > canonical, i only see indicator, unity-2d and unity-greeter.

Ubuntu: 12.04.3
GPU: GTX 570 SOC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ***Dconf-Editor***... go to **desktop -> unity**

*(This is the **com.canonical.Unity** schema)*

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast response Roman, i was searching for this option: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/dconf.jpg

Comment: glad to help!. yes the key form-factor is in that scheme, but the image in your link is for Ubuntu 12.10 & 13.04. for 12.04 is in desktop>unity. please consider mark this answer as accepted, by clicking the green check mark. Thanks